# Changing the suite bar - how do I keep branding consistant?

Tags: 2013

I've edited my suite bar to put a hyperlink behind the word 'SharePoint' (top left in the image below) to send the user back to the home page of the farm with the following powershell script:

[image]

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

$containerCode = @"
<div id='webTitleContainer' class='ms-core-brandingText'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {

    // Set a default title to use if we cannot retrieve one.
    var defaultTitle = '<a href="http://ccq">SharePoint</a>';

    // Ensure that both the DOM and the Object Model are ready for us
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        EnsureScriptFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

            // Instantiate our renamer.
            var t = new titleBarRenamer();

        });
    });


    function titleBarRenamer() {

        // Get and load a reference to the root web of the current site collection.
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var site = ctx.get_site();
        var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();

        ctx.load(rootWeb);

        // Send our query off to SharePoint.
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {

            var title = false;

            // Pull the title into a variable.
            // Default to the default title if it fails.

            try {

            //    title = defaultTitle + ' - ' + rootWeb.get_title();
                title = defaultTitle
                title = title || defaultTitle;

            } catch (e) {

                title = defaultTitle;

            }

            // Update our title to our results.
            document.getElementById('webTitleContainer').innerHTML = title;

        }, function() {

            // If all else fails, set the title back to our default.
            document.getElementById('webTitleContainer').innerHTML = defaultTitle;

        });

    }

})();
</script>
"@

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://sharepoint"
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = $containerCode
$webApp.Update()
```

The trouble I'm having is that now this styles completely differently to the rest of the links in the suite bar. Is  there a way to make it use the same style as my other links (top right, "Newsfeed", for example).

Comment: Completely differing? Looks like you need to set either a class on a tag, or put style="color:#FFF" on it

Comment: @Robert Lindgren Is  there a way to use the same style though (I don't know what it's called)... I don't want to have to change this each time the masterpage changes (irregular, but will happen at some point)

Comment: You can use for example Firebug to identify the class that SharePoint adds on the other links, on the right hand side and use this class.